# About the infinite solutions of a Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the following problem:
$$\sum_{k=1}^N k^2=q^2$$
where q is an integer number. This can be written as:
$$\frac{1}{3}N^3+\frac{1}{2}N^2+\frac{1}{6}N=q^2$$
In the same way we can write:
$$\sum_{k=1}^N k^3=q^3$$
that means:
$$\frac{1}{4}N^4+\frac{1}{2}N^3+\frac{1}{4}N^2=q^3$$
In general, we can consider the following equation:
$$\sum_{k=1}^N k^r=q^r$$
with $r$ integer number.
The question is: does this equation has infinite solutions for every $r$ integer?
Thanks.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{4}N^4+\frac{1}{2}N^3+\frac{1}{4}N^2=\left(\frac{N(N+1)}2\right)^2$$

Comment: I see. How this could give an answer to the question?

Comment: this was just an observation, never an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, Schaffer proved in 1956 that the equation
$$
\sum_{k=1}^K k^r = q^n
$$
has at most finitely many solutions unless 
$$
(r,n) \in \{ (1,2), (3,2), (3,4), (5,2) \}.
$$
The proof uses Siegel's theorem (though, as Erick notes, Faltings would lead to the same conclusion).

Answer (score 1):

Not always,when $r=2$, the equation $x(x+1)(2x+1)=6y^2$ has only these solutions:$(x,y)=(0,0)(-1,0)(1,±1)(24,±70).$

Comment: Is r=2 the only possible value for which the equation doesn't have infinite solutions?

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra By Faltings's Theorem, it is atypical for curves of degree $>2$ to admit infinitely many solutions, so one would guess this is the exact opposite of the truth unless you know of some special structure here.